# why Zend_Db_Adapter is much slower than mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, zend-framework, zend-db

I use Zend Framework in my project. I need to insert multiple records and I found that Zend_Db suprisingly slower thatn my_sql query (several times), that made me think I did something wrong.
Here are two examples.

Zend_Db_Adapter:

```
        $startTime = microtime(true);
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $db->beginTransaction();

        $dateAdded = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $lastChanged = $dateAdded;                  

        foreach ($importDataNamespace->data as $subscriberNum => $subscriber)
        {
            foreach ($fieldsMap as $fieldNumber => $fieldTag) {
                if (isset($subscriber[$fieldNumber])) {
                    $subscriberData[$fieldTag] = $subscriber[$fieldNumber]; 
                } else {
                    $subscriberData[$fieldTag] = '';
                }
            }
            $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) ' .
                     'VALUES (' . 52 . ', ' . 29 . ', ' .  $db->quote($subscriberData['EMAIL']) . ', ' . $db->quote($subscriberData['FNAME']) .
                     ', ' . $db->quote($subscriberData['LNAME']) . ', ' . $db->quote($dateAdded) . ', ' . $db->quote($lastChanged) . ')';
            $db->query($query);                                                                 
        }
        $db->commit();

        $this->view->time = microtime(true) - $startTime;
```

Example with mysql_query:

```
        $startTime = microtime(true);

        $user = 'root';
        $password = 'password';
        $db = 'database';
        $connect = @mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$password) or die("Failed to connect database");
        @mysql_select_db($db) or die("Failed to select database");          

        $dateAdded = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $lastChanged = $dateAdded;      

        $result = mysql_query('SET autocommit = 0');            

        foreach ($importDataNamespace->data as $subscriberNum => $subscriber)
        {
            foreach ($fieldsMap as $fieldNumber => $fieldTag) {
                if (isset($subscriber[$fieldNumber])) {
                    $subscriberData[$fieldTag] = $subscriber[$fieldNumber]; 
                } else {
                    $subscriberData[$fieldTag] = '';
                }
            }
            $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) ' .
                'VALUES (' . 52 . ', ' . 29 . ', \'' .  mysql_real_escape_string($subscriberData['EMAIL']) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subscriberData['FNAME']) .
                '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($subscriberData['LNAME']) . '\', \'' . $dateAdded . '\', \'' . $lastChanged . '\')';                    
            mysql_query($query);                                    
        }
        $result = mysql_query('SET autocommit = 1');
        $result = mysql_query('COMMIT;');

        $this->view->time = microtime(true) - $startTime;
```

In the first case it took 14.8 seconds, in the second 3.7.
Could you tell me why does it happend and what do you do wrong?

If I delete any quote for Zend_Db it took 12 seconds from 14 with quote, but it's still much more slower than with mysql_query:

```
        $startTime = microtime(true);
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $db->beginTransaction();

        $dateAdded = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $lastChanged = $dateAdded;                  

        foreach ($importDataNamespace->data as $subscriberNum => $subscriber)
        {
            foreach ($fieldsMap as $fieldNumber => $fieldTag) {
                if (isset($subscriber[$fieldNumber])) {
                    $subscriberData[$fieldTag] = $subscriber[$fieldNumber]; 
                } else {
                    $subscriberData[$fieldTag] = '';
                }
            }
            $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) ' .
                     'VALUES (' . 52 . ', ' . 29 . ', \'' .  $subscriberData['EMAIL'] . '\', \'' . $subscriberData['FNAME'] .
                     '\', \'' . $subscriberData['LNAME'] . '\', \'' . $dateAdded . '\', \'' . $lastChanged . '\')';
            $db->query($query);                                                         
        }
        $db->commit();

        $this->view->time = microtime(true) - $startTime;
```

Thank you for any information about this issue.

This code takes about 0.065 seconds with mysql_query:

```
    $dateAdded = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $lastChanged = $dateAdded;      

    $startTime = microtime(true);       
    $result = mysql_query('BEGIN');
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $email = 'test_ ' . $i . '@gmail.com';
        $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) ' .
                'VALUES (' . 52 . ', ' . 29 . ', \'' .  mysql_real_escape_string($email) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($firstName) .
                '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($lastName) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($dateAdded) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($lastChanged) . '\')';                                                                   
        mysql_query($query);            
    }               
    $result = mysql_query('COMMIT');
    $time = microtime(true) - $startTime;                           
    echo 'Using mysql_query: ' . $time  . '<br />';
    exit();
```

Code with benchmark of Zend_Db_Adapter (I didn't even use quote in this case):

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);
    $profiler = $db->getProfiler();          

    $startTime = microtime(true);
    $db->beginTransaction();        
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
    {

        $email = 'test_' . $i . '@gmail.com';
        $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) ' .
             'VALUES (' . 52 . ', ' . 29 . ', \'' . $email . '\', \'' . $firstName .
             '\', \'' . $lastName . '\', \'' . $dateAdded . '\', \'' . $lastChanged . '\')';
        $db->query($query);                                 
    }           
    $db->commit();
    $time = microtime(true) - $startTime;                       
    echo 'Time of transaction Zend_Db_Adapter query: ' . $time . '<br />';

    echo 'Total time ' . $profiler->getTotalElapsedSecs() . '<br />';           
    $count = 0;
    $totalTime = 0; 
    foreach ($profiler->getQueryProfiles() as $query) {
        $count++;
        $elapsedTime = $query->getElapsedSecs();
        $totalTime += $elapsedTime;
        echo $count . ' ' . $elapsedTime  . ' ' . $query->getQuery() . '<br />';
    }
    echo 'Sum time: ' . $totalTime . '<br />';
```

Here are some results:

Time of transaction Zend_Db_Adapter query: 0.23094701767
Total time 0.0949234962463
1 0.00199699401855 connect
2 0.000336885452271 begin
3 0.000540018081665 INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) VALUES (52, 29, 'test_0@gmail.com', 'John', 'Clinton', '2011-01-28 15:25:21', '2011-01-28 15:25:21')
4 0.000504016876221 INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) VALUES (52, 29, 'test_1@gmail.com', 'John', 'Clinton', '2011-01-28 15:25:21', '2011-01-28 15:25:21')

It's very strange. The time of transacation to insert 100 records is 2.5 times more than executing of all queries.
If I try to meach the time of forming strings in the loop it (if we delete query) doesn't take so much time.

Comment: If you have a big system with lots of data, you may consider doctrine2 as an ORM

Comment: Yes, it's going to have rather much data. But the problem with Zend_Db_Adapter is still unclear, what cause it to take so long.

Answer (score 3):

I think that one reason is that you execute $db->quote() too many times, which is unnecessary. Do you know that $db->quote() can take an array as its argument and you can basically reduce calls to $db->quote() to only one. In addition in your mysql_query version you do not escape $dateAdded and $lastChanged, while in zend_db version you do.

EDIT: Added an example below

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    $input = array(
        'a' => "asd'lfksd",
        'b' => "asdlfk'sdfasdf",
        'c' => "asd fds f saf'sdfsd",
        'd' => "asd fds f saf'sdfsd"
    );


    // separate calls to quote
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    $db->quote($input['a']);
    $db->quote($input['b']);
    $db->quote($input['c']);
    $db->quote($input['d']);
    $totalTime1 = microtime(true) - $startTime;



    // one call to quote
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    $db->quote($input);
    $totalTime2 = microtime(true) - $startTime;

    // show results
    var_dump("Sperate calls are ". $totalTime1/$totalTime2 . " times slower");
    //output: string 'Sperate calls are 3.0875831485588 times slower' (length=46)
```

Comment: Do you think quote can take some much time?

Comment: I didn't think that quote can take array as argument. I didn't find it in the documentation. I used many mysqli_real_escape_string in the second case too.

Comment: @user366534. I added an example code that you can use to check the time difference between single call to quote vs. many calls to quote.

Comment: I added code whne I delete any quote for zend_db it take now 12 seconds (from 14 seconds) which is much slower than mysql_query (3.8) even when I added quote for date fields too.

Comment: @user366534. In this case I think you need to do small tests to localize what is so slow. You can, for example, just measure time for only execution of $db->query($query) and mysql_query($query) and see if this is the source of the problem. You can remove transactions and see what happens. Also, are you sure that in both cases your data (i.e. $importDataNamespace->data is identical). If you find something interesting, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to make some benchmarks like these and let you know about results.

Comment: If we remove transaction before cycle it the performance will be worse, not matter if we use Zend_Adapter or mysql_query. The overhead of starting and committing a transaction for every row is rather serious.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to measure time of making one query because it's rather small and this values are constantly changes. To see a different it's necessary to add a loop. When I add a loop I see that with Zend_Db_Adapter performance is 3-4 times worse.

Comment: It looks strange. I maded some more benchmarks using Profiler for Zend_Db_Adapter. I'll add code.

Comment: @user366534. Maybe Zend_Db is indeed that slow.

Comment: You might take a look at the benchmarks it seems strange. The time of executing of all queries and connection is much slower that the time of script's work. And I can't understnand why it takes so much to execute.

Comment: If I increase cycle to 1000 result are like this: Time of transaction Zend_Db_Adapter query: 2.79931116104
Total time 0.567594051361
1 0.0019998550415 connect
2 0.000346899032593 begin
3 0.000557899475098 INSERT INTO subscribers (list_id, account_id, email_address, first_name, last_name, date_added, last_changed) VALUES (52, 29, 'test_0@gmail.com', 'John', 'Clinton', '2011-01-28 15:31:54', '2011-01-28 15:31:54')

Comment: @user366534. It is not a surprise that 'Total time' is lower than 'Time of transaction Zend_Db_Adapter query'. The reason is that when you use Zend_Db_Profiler it measures the execution time of a query only. However, when you  measure 'Time of transaction Zend_Db_Adapter query' you measure everything, including execution of the query, running Db_Profiler, preparation of the query, and everything else that goes on top in ZF. So you cannot directly compare 'Total time' with 'Time of transaction Zend_Db_Adapter query' as they measure different things.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this time much be more, but the so large different is rather suprising to me.

Comment: I run your banchmark code on my computer (with simmilar sql) and I got similar difference than you got. So maybe this is how it is. Anyway, thanks. It was very informative discussion and exercise with zend_db:-)

Comment: Could you tell please what version of Zend Framework on your machine.

Comment: Simply the ratio on two machine was different: On Windows machine and ZF 1.10.5 it the difference is more that on test server Devian ZF 1.10.8 (it seems to me on the last machine the different is less). I can't find explaintion of it now.

Comment: As far as I can judge quote doesn't work with arrays, I passed to quote array, then I displayed the elements of array, it looks like they remained unchanged. For example test0@gmail.com remained the same, not 'test0@gmail.com' as it becomes if I apply it to element of array not array.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_* functions are natives to PHP , so they are very fast.

Zend_Db_Adapter is working with PDO so you have a first absraction layer with PDO and a second with Zend_DB_Adapter.

More layer abstraction you 've got , more the code is slowing down.

That why the MVC framework in general are more slower than procedural code.

Try again your benchmark with prepared statement and a cache mechanism and you should be close of the mysql_* functions

Comment: Yes, I expected it to be a little slower, but several time slower, it seems too much. I

Comment: And it sure highlights the benefits of a good server-side caching strategy to avoid those costly db connections and queries wherever possible.

Comment: I don't quite understand how caching could help inserting multiple rows.

Comment: Caching will not improve the database connection itself but the computing time of the abstraction layers will be reduce.

Comment: As far as I can judge it can help mostly with reading not writing.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you don't have a metadata cache in Zend_Db.

Comment: Could you please, explain what you mean there?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean about a metadata cache in Zend_Db?

Comment: You can read more here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.metadata.caching. Hopefully this will help with your problem though it could be a red herring. I make it a habit of always using a metadata cache in Zend_Db to prevent useless queries from being sent to the DB.